# Remove onclick on anchor tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

What's the best way to remove or disable an onclick event on an anchor tag? Here's the html we have set up:

```
<a onclick="doSomething('')" href="#"><div id="link-text">Link here</div></a>
```

Tried something like this but it doesn't appear to work:

```
$('[id="cswp-like-text').parent().prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

Comment: you can try `$('a').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // your code here });`

Comment: Your selector is invalid `'[id="cswp-like-text'`

Comment: [Setting `onclick` attribute to null works](https://jsfiddle.net/n6fd79z2/).

Comment: The best way to remove the `onclick` event-handling is to not have it in the HTML. Why is it there, if it's unwanted?

Comment: @DavidThomas Maybe OP want to disable the button after one click

Comment: @Mikey: while that's possible it seems unlikely that anyone would deliberately introduce an `onclick` event-handler in the HTML to run once (or any number of *n* times) and then use jQuery - and unobtrusive JavaScript - to remove it. I'd guess it's legacy HTML that needs a refactor, an update and a tidy of some kind.

Comment: @DavidThomas correct, the onclick event pre-exists on all the pages and we just want to disable this on a few pages without having to modifying the existing code structure.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
With the new philosophy of [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), mixing HTML with JS code  is recommended!.

It is considered a bad practice to embed your js code inside  html elements (`onclick="function(){}"` for example ),
instead you are encouraged to define events on a script section or inside an external .js file

Coming back to your question you can take advantage of the **addEventListener()** and **removeEventListener()** methods provided by JavaScript and supported by modern web browsers, here is a simple example using pure JavaScript (vanilla) :

```
<a href="#" id="link">mylink</a>
```

and here the js part of it :

```
// a function to be executed whenever an event occur 


var myFunction = function (){
      console.log('element with id link is clicked ');
    };

     var a = document.getElementById('link');
    // add event listener for the click event 
    a.addEventListener('click',myFunction);

    // remove the event listener 
    a.removeEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

A jquery equivalente solution is to use **.unbind('event name')** :

```
var a = $('#link');
$(a).unbind('click');
```